# object cannot be cast from DB Null or other types

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview in my windows application.In which i want to calculate total amount using the datagridview cell(from qty,price,tax,discount) values and display in the total gridview cell.
But i am getting this error.i had also taken nullable type also.How to overcome with this problem.
    ?
    here is my cellendedit event code

```
 private void datagrid_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            int val1 = Convert.ToInt32(datagrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value);
            int val2 = Convert.ToInt32(datagrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value);
            int val3 = Convert.ToInt32(datagrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Value);
            int val4 = Convert.ToInt32(datagrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Value);

                datagrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[6].Value = ((val2 + val3) * val1) - val4;

        }
```

Comment: you'll need to check if each cell value is null or not before converting it to Int32

Comment: Maybe it is good idea to have calculated column in your data source?

Answer (score 0):

The issue you have if that one of your cells is DBNull.Value. Generally I would check to see if a cell is not equal to DBNull.Value, and then convert it to an in. If you value is infact a true null, then I also assume setting your value to 0 would be fine.

```
int value1 = datagrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value == DBNull.Value ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(datagrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the `int.TryParse` method instead of `Convert.ToInt`.